# Replacing a blob with a new blob in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, blob

We have a situation where we want to replace a blob in the cloud with a new file.  It seems like the file in the cloud is getting truncated to zero length if there's a network interruption during the transfer.  Is there a pattern where we can replace a blob with a new blob, but only end up with the old blob intact or the new blob intact instead of a blank blob?

We wanted to use rename for this, but there isn't rename functionality, and the blob copy function is not guaranteed to work within a reasonable period of time.

Or is our assumption about how the blob is becoming zero length incorrect?

Comment: Can you share some code? The behavior you're seeing should not be happening.